# Can I use the same RecyclerView adapter for two different activities for two different data classes?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have created a RecyclerView. I want to add another RecyclerView  to another activity in my app which displays different layout and different data (uses different data class). can I do it with same adapter that I created? if yes, then please tell how? if by getItemViewType() then how to differentiate between two activities to set the respective view holder and how to add two data classes? please help.  I am working in Kotlin, please give a kotlin example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest you not to do so. From the maintance perspective, it would just make you code harder to understand and update later. Even if that means you need more code.

If you really want to do so, you could provide additional parameter to the adapter class - a Boolean for example, that will tell you which activity are you in right now and for which data it has to be prepared.
And having that, you can just add an if condition in every place you need sth different depending on a data class youre using. And thats it.

Comment: Thank you so much mate. how can I use two data classes in the adapter. I initialize the arraylist like this "class AlertAdapter(var alerts : List<AlertData> ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AlertAdapter.AlertViewHolder>() {"

Comment: Just add another list as an adapter argument and make them both nullable so that you can distinguish them based on which one is null

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much mate.